# THREE.js - Can someone please explain how to use this library?

Tags: three.js

I downloaded three.js (three.js-master) and am confused by what I'm seeing because of the following 3 things:
- There is a Three.Legacy.js vs a Three.js under the /src folder.
- Also under the /src folder there are various smaller files (e.g. scene.js). 
- Under /examples/js there are even more various files.

**Question**

If I want to create a new application using the latest & greatest version of Three.js, what files must I be referencing?

thanks.

**Update**

So I discovered that three.js exists under /src AND under /build. The one under /src is a mere 7 KB in size while the other one is 949 KB. The 7KB file has many things missing. What is the purpose of this file and why does it even exist? It's simply confusing.

Comment: Just the main minified three.js. That's all you need to start with.

Comment: Use the _non-minified_ file `three.js` for development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Documentation says that you only need the three.js so use the `three.min.js` inside `build` folder is the best.

In practical development, we should not edit the source code, that's why they write every new and/or customised feature into separate small files.

http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene

Comment: Ok. then what on earth are all the other files for? They seem relevant. Also, what is the difference between three.js and three.legacy.js?

Comment: Also, why is Three.js only 7 KB while Three.Legacy.js is 24 KB !?

Comment: So things like THREE.PerspectiveCamera are simply not defined. This explains why its only 7 KB.

Comment: You're right! Let's imagine, that is the core framework, the engine, and now when you grab it to build your custom car, you are free to put anything you want, like 3 wheels, you don't need a cover or doors, it's ok. The bare-bone engine is really lightweight.